# Flutter convert Widget to Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, bloc

I have a main screen with several Buttons which push the user to different screens and I have a FAB which pushs the user to a screen he saved as favorite. I do this with a cubit from BLoC: (FAB onPress function): `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  state.favWidget!));` 
Problem: I try to save the state of the Cubit (Shared prefs or Hydrated, dosent matter for me - I prefere HydratedCubit) so that the user reaches his favorite screen even after a restart.

Here is the FavWidgetState:

```
class FavWidgetState extends Equatable {
  factory FavWidgetState.initial() {
    return const FavWidgetState(favWidget: null);
  }

   final Widget? favWidget;


  const FavWidgetState({
    required this.favWidget,
  });
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'favWidget': this.favWidget,
    };
  }

  factory FavWidgetState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FavWidgetState(
      favWidget: json['favWidget'] as Widget,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [favWidget];
```

I added the fromJson and toJson with the dart dataclass extention

Inside FaveWidgetcubit is just little code:

```
 FavWidgetCubit() : super(FavWidgetState.initial());


  void setFaveWidget({required Widget? widget})async{
    emit(FavWidgetState(favWidget: widget));
  }
  

  @override
  FavWidgetState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FavWidgetState.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(FavWidgetState state) {
      return state.toJson();
  }
```

You can imagine that this won't with the error: `Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of ...`
How do I make the `Widget? widget` to a convertible object?

Comment: I don't think your approach will work. Why don't you save the route as a string in Json? If you use Cubit for navigation, you could store some key or whatever you use to manage the navigation state. Or you use named routes and then you can store the name of the route

Comment: Named Routs which I define in my MaterialApp works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot